# Использование CompletableFuture в высоконагруженной среде

Tags: java, многопоточность

Короткая предыстория: я довольно быстро перескочил с PHP на Java, поэтому некоторые вопросы (типа этого) требуют дополнительной консультации.

Есть некоторое потенциально высоконагруженное веб-приложение, предполагается до тысячи одновременных запросов. Одна из ручек приложения занимается сборкой сущностей из разных таблиц в БД. Для ускорения этого процесса хочется задействовать свежи модни CompletableFuture, обернув в него каждую операцию и совершив запросы ко всем этим таблицам в параллель. Эта модель прекрасно сработает при одном единовременном запросе, но я не уверен, что она хорошо масштабируется, и что (в связи с нехваткой ресурсов и ограниченным количеством подключений к БД, раздаваемых через пул) я не получу наоборот, более медленное приложение. Понятно, что точного прогноза без детального анализа дать невозможно, но я бы хотел услышать *предполагаемое быстродействие и поведение* приложения при переходе от полностью синхронной обработки каждого запроса к обработке с использованием асинхронности.

Я знаю, что по-хорошему при таких задачах надо перейти вообще на иную архитектурную модель (akka / vert.x), но в данный момент это невозможно.

Comment: Боюсь что Akka/Vert.x используют туже модель. Разве что отличаются названия соответствующих абстракций. Вопрос не очень понятен. Вы хотите измерить производительность `CompletableFuture`? Она молниеносна, т.к. вызов метода `complete` ничего не стоит (за вычетом возможных внутренних CAS или volatile операций). Масштабиремость модели определенно зависит еще и от профиля нагрузки. Если у вас интенсивный IO, то модель будет работать хорошо и вы упретесь в БД. Если у вас массивные вычисления, то это уже совсем другая история. Модель все еще подходит, но кол-во потоков должно быть невелико.

Comment: @a_gura я пока не могу точно спрогнозировать количество потоков, но, насколько могу предположить, оно перевалит за сотню, и я пока впервые имею дело с подобной конфигурацией и боюсь неизвестных подводных камней. Насколько понимаю, в vert.x все-таки всё немного по-другому - есть event loop'ы в произвольном количестве, которые могут быть созданы по одному на ядро, а внутри event loop'а все выполняется в однопоточном контексте, и никаких расходов на переключение потоков нет.

Comment: Расходы на переключение потоков будут почти всегда, если только не использовать привязку потока к ядру, чего в Java из коробки нет. А в случае с IO-bound профилем нагрузки, переключение контекстов вообще некритично. В общем мой поинт в том, что сравнивать фреймворки типа Vert.x с `CompletableFuture` вцелом некорректно, а на ваш вопрос нельзя дать однозначного ответа.

Comment: @a_gura ага, понял